# How long should "Update Profile Info" take to refresh?

Tags: bug, network-profile

When I tried to "update the profile" on network Stack-Exchange profile page yesterday, it hasn't reflected 24 hours later ...

How long is it supposed to take?

---

Steps to repro:

1. Update the Stack overflow profile. (I was removing some information like twitter links)
2. Go to Stack exchange network profile (Click  "Update Profile Info" and select the Stackoverflow profile)
3. Wait anxiously
4. Keep refreshing the page
5. 24 hours later - nothing happens

Comment: Some jobs run only once 48 hours but I do recall the network profile is stubborn. Can you try changing the twitter url to something else (so not empty) and see if that has a better effect?

Comment: @rene more likely the synch on se.com takes from some cache that wasn't synched yet, i.e. need to wait for a while after changing a site profile, before synching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It updates immediately - there is no delay when using the dropdown to manually copy changes. If it doesn't catch all the changes to your profile, try just copying from another site. It's usually enough to kick it into changing properly. If that still doesn't work, you can contact us and we can delete the "profile" there to reset it to auto-syncing.

Given we plan to eventually remove the ability to do *anything at all* on stackexchange.com itself, it is unlikely we will ever invest time trying to fix this feature.

Comment: I just made a stackoverflow for business account, and then tried to update the profile. Thanks for removing it now.

Comment: "can delete the "profile" there to reset it to auto-syncing" - what do you mean by that? As far as I know there's no auto synch anymore for years.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard Probably has something to do with the fact that logging in directly on stackexchange.com creates a physical profile - I think he's talking about deleting that physical profile.

Comment: @Sonic oh, I see. When the network profile is created, it would automatically take the oldest profile. So deleting it will cause it to be created again on next log in. Thanks. :)